# How to align items vertically by columns, BUT not align them horizontally inside columns

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid, masonry

I made a sketch of the layout that I need to make: [drawing of the desired layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYMmH.jpg)

**My problem is:**
how to make articles "4" and "5" position themselves according to the height of the article which is positioned above them, and are not aligned

I tried with these 3 solutions without success:

1. With CSS Grid: CSS grid allows me to position the 5 elements as desired EXCEPT this height alignment problem!
   With CSS grid, elements "4" and "5" are aligned regardless of the height of element "2" and "3"
2. With CSS Flex: CSS flex allows me to position the 5 elements as desired EXCEPT this height alignment problem!

I got help from [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Aligning_Items_in_a_Flex_Container#aligning_one_item_with_align-self) but even using "align-items" and "align-self" I can't get items "4" and "5" to rise proportionally to the height of items "2" and "3"

3. MASONRY: I also tried with this method:

   [Masonry method URL](https://w3bits.com/css-masonry/)
   [DEMO url](https://w3bits.com/labs/css-masonry/)

   This method uses columns in CSS:

   ```
   .masonry { /\* Masonry container \*/
   column-count: 4;
   column-gap: 1em;
   }

   .item { /\* Masonry bricks or child elements \*/
   background-color: #eee;
    display: inline-block;
   margin: 0 0 1em;
   width: 100%;
   }
   ```

My problem with this method is that the items display in order vertically inside the columns

This is a news site and the order in which the elements are displayed is very important: the elements must be displayed in order horizontally

Comment: Just to go completely off-topic, if you're doing layout sketches then this is a really handy website: https://excalidraw.com/  Worth a look imho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;  
}    
.item {
  background-color: green;
  margin: 10px;
}
.col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col col1">
      <div class="item">Item 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col2">
      <div class="item">Item 2</div>
      <div class="item">Item 4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col3">
      <div class="item">Item 3</div>
      <div class="item">Item 5</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without a working snippet of code its hard to debug, but if I'm understanding correctly I would do as follows.

Use the flexbox method that got you most of the way there, but place columns 2 + 3 in a seperate `<div>` this will make columns 4 + 5 align below it starting at the absolute bottom of the largest column of 2 + 3.

Alternatively, set a `min-height` to all the columns, making them all align at the same height.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [Macy.js](http://macyjs.com). To summon up the docs:

Use the script tag to include:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/macy@2"></script>
```

And add the following code in JavaScript:

```
var macy = Macy({
    container: '#macy-container', //Change to the parent element of the articals
    trueOrder: true,
    waitForImages: false, //If there are images set this to true
    margin: 24, //The gap between the columns
    columns: 2, //Total columns
    breakAt: { //Columns for each screen width (optional)
        1200: 5,
        940: 3,
        520: 2,
        400: 1
    }
});
```

Check the docs for more info.